# Counting the number of values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to write a program that counts the number of values in a dictionary.

For example, say I have this dictionary.

```
{'a': ['aardvark'], 'b': ['baboon'], 'c': ['coati'], 'd': ['donkey', 'dog', 'dingo']}
```

I should get 6 as a result, because there's 6 values.

When I use this code, I get 4.

```
def how_many(aDict):

    sum = len(aDict.values())

    return sum

animals = {'a': ['aardvark'], 'b': ['baboon'], 'c': ['coati'], 'd': ['donkey', 'dog', 'dingo']}

print(how_many(animals))
```

I'm very new to Python so please don't do anything to hard.

Answer (score 3):

You need to sum the lengths of each of the elements in `aDict.values()`:

```
>>> aDict = {'a': ['aardvark'], 'b': ['baboon'], 'c': ['coati'], 'd': ['donkey', 'dog', 'dingo']}
>>> sum(len(item) for item in aDict.values())
6
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [**`sum`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) on the *generator expression* to calculate [**`len`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) of each value as:

```
>>> my_dict = {'a': ['aardvark'], 'b': ['baboon'], 'c': ['coati'], 'd': ['donkey', 'dog', 'dingo']}

#       returns list of all values v
>>> sum(len(v) for v in my_dict.values())
6
```

*Alternatively*, you may also use [**`map`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) with `sum` to achieve this as:

```
>>> sum(map(len, my_dict.values()))
6
```